# How to delete or remove the unapplied migrations in django?

Tags: python, django-forms

While starting my local server in Django, it shows me "17 unapplied migrations.." How can I remove this content while starting the server?

i am trying on this on my Windows Server 10

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
July 30, 2019 - 14:53:53
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'CalcProject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[30/Jul/2019 14:53:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
[30/Jul/2019 14:53:58] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[30/Jul/2019 14:53:58] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[30/Jul/2019 14:53:58] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply migrations use command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

To remove migrations use fake command

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

but be careful before using this command .

Answer (score 0):

Is there a good reason why you don't want to apply the migrations, which set up the Django environment in your database? If not, then as the message suggests, just execute

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: i have configured django with mysql and was checking the connection by doing migrations, But now, while starting server each time i am getting like " Your migrations are unapplied", That's the reason !!

Comment: So when you try to migrate it appears to work but the message is still there next time you start?

Comment: yeah...and could you suggest the solution for the below one !!
###
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
###
it tells me Unable to import 'django.contrib' ,and  i am doing this in visual studio

Comment: Something is very sick with you installation if you can't import Django libraries. Have you done any testing from `manage.py shell`? e.g. trying to type in the import statements. If you can't import django components then that needs to be addressed before anything else. By the way, the error message you cite doesn't match the import statements, if you do `from django.contrib import admin` and `django.contrib` isn't available, it would say `no module named django.contrib`. Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: I have fixed it.The problem is i didn't chose the python interpreter in visual studio.
Thanks now its working fine.